# How to use Django-jet with Django-oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar, django-jet

I am trying to integrate `Django-jet` with `Django-oscar`, but keep getting the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't
>   unique, duplicates: dashboard

I have tried removing oscar core dashboard app from the installed apps list using `OSCAR_HIDDEN_FEATURES` but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for this is for the apps packaged by both packages should follow the new convention of [using an `AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#for-application-authors) that can be subclassed and modified (to change the app label).

Unfortunately neither `django-jet` nor `django-oscar` 1.6 follow this practise, so you are a bit stuck. Django 2.0 (just released) has moved to use app configs, so your best bet is to use that and [subclass Oscar's dashboard app](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/dashboard/apps.py#L10) to give it a different label. You would then list your subclass in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of the default one.

Side note - Oscar provides it's own dashboard that is completely independent of the Django admin. I am not sure there is much to be gained by combining these two packages in the same project.

`OSCAR_HIDDEN_FEATURES` is not relevant here - it only controls what is visible in the front end, not what apps are loaded.